# Google Cloud Dataflow jobs failing, inaccessible jars & 410 gone errors

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

A number of my Google Cloud Dataflow jobs failed yesterday, reporting internal errors that I have not seen before.

Here are two examples:
Job ID 2016-01-31_12_14_47-10166346951693629111 failed with the following error:

```
Jan 31, 2016, 10:15:25 PM
(bc20d8395f1f7459): Staged package jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310-3EcW9gR7xsTM1TnqPH__rQ.jar at location 'gs://XXXXXXXXX/jetty-servlet-9.2.10.v20150310-3EcW9gR7xsTM1TnqPH__rQ.jar' is inaccessible.
```

and job ID 2016-01-31_12_22_11-15290010907236071290 failed with this error:

```
Jan 31, 2016, 11:13:58 PM
(56214ba1d51ca7d6): java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone { "code" : 500, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Backend Error", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Backend Error" }
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:431)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:289)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextSink$TextFileWriter.close(TextSink.java:243)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:254)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:191)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:144)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:180)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:161)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:148)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone { "code" : 500, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Backend Error", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Backend Error" }
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357) ... 4 more
```

Was there any maintenance or other work occurring on the Dataflow service that might have caused these errors?

Comment: These errors look like they are problems interacting with Google Cloud Storage. Have you successfully run jobs before? Is this still a problem? Has anything changed with your project (eg., permissions on cloud storage buckets, quota, etc.)?

Comment: It was last run about a month ago without any issues, and nothing has changed in terms of bucket permissions or quotas. I've also just checked and both the Dataflow job and bucket are in the same region.

Comment: It's unclear at this stage, is this issue still occurring?